# Is it possible to get full path to a OneDrive item?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using the MS Graph SDK in a C# project to search through people's OneDrives for specific terms in files and folders.  When I find one, I've not found a way to get the full path for a DriveItem?

Not the URL path, but the file system path where the owning user stores the file locally.

Is this possible?

Comment: So, through much trial and error, and with the help of both answers below, I figured out the issue.  My scenario is that I'm using the "Search" functionality in the Graph API (request: https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/<user_id>/drive/root/microsoft.graph.search(q='<search_term>').  The issue is that while this endpoint returns a list of DriveItems that match the search criteria, these DriveItems are NOT populated with ParentReference.Path.  So, I solved this issue by re-requesting the DriveItem explicitly from the search results and that has the necessary meta data populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you request the metadata for a drive item you receive for example:

```
{
    "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=c8b43b37-bc76-4352-af27-5a8e9f1bbfeb&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.eWQzcTFxNmhBb0txNFNnZzQyNlIyU2gzaUQwSGJxbC9abWRlVVZ3OGUwMD0&ApiVersion=2.0",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:17:44Z",
    "eTag": "\"{C8B43B37-BC76-4352-AF27-5A8E9F1BBFEB},2\"",
    "id": "01BYE5RZZXHO2MQ5V4KJB26J22R2PRXP7L",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:17:44Z",
    "name": "Camera Customer Analysis.xlsx",
    "webUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BC8B43B37-BC76-4352-AF27-5A8E9F1BBFEB%7D&file=Camera%20Customer%20Analysis.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true",
    "cTag": "\"c:{C8B43B37-BC76-4352-AF27-5A8E9F1BBFEB},1\"",
    "size": 2675045,
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
            "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
            "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
        }
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd",
        "driveType": "business",
        "id": "01BYE5RZ6TAJHXA5GMWZB2HDLD7SNEXFFU",
        "path": "/drive/root:/CR-227 Project"
    },
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "hashes": {
            "quickXorHash": "qz9+NLaGwZCFBcd9gH+HCNUVcn8="
        }
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:17:44Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:17:44Z"
    }
}
```

As you can see it contains a `parentReference` which contains the `path`
To get the full path, substring the `path` starting at the first `:` and append the `name`.
In the above example it would give: `/CR-227 Project/Camera Customer Analysis.xlsx`

[Doc reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/itemReference#remarks)

However, getting the local path where the user stored the file locally is not stored by Microsoft. But you can reproduce it because the OneDrive file structure will be the same as the local one.

Comment: I believe this is what I need, but I think I'm doing something incorrectly when it comes to requesting the DriveItem in the first place.  NOTE:  I'm using the Graph SDK libraries.  The problem is that if I look at the "ParentReference" object, the "Path" is not populated.  Ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, we can't use  the Graph API to get the  root directory of the OneDrive local file system. We can only get the relative path of the OneDrive item.

My test configuration: local storage directory: C:/onedrive. The file  is stored in “C:/onedrive/Test Floder/”.  We can only get the “path /drive/root:Test”.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aegR.png)

The repro steps:
We can try the following API to get the relative path for the user's OneDrive settings first:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/children .
Then, you can stitch the file system path set by the user with the relative path obtained from the API.

We can set different file system paths on the local system for OneDrive. You can refer to this article to set the local storage location for OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a FileInfo object from the url path. The local physical path can then be obtained from this object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).